# Fail to generate .exe using makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I write a simple C program like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

And I also write a makefile:

```
test: main.o
    gcc -o test main.o

main.o:main.c
    gcc -c -o main.o main.c
```

And they are in the same file:
[image]
But here comes an error when I try to use make:
[image]
Then I try in this way and it works:
[image]

Why can't I generate test.exe using make?Is there anything wrong with the makefile?I'm new and any advice will help^_^

Comment: Please just paste your code here (using the code formatting) instead of attaching screenshots. No-one else can save, compile and execute your screenshots!

Comment: BTW, you're running Microsoft make rather than gnu make, so make sure you're looking at the right documentation. Or run gnu make and see if it's error is more helpful.

Comment: one possibility is the `make` is not using the correct `make.exe`. Suggest examine your PATH environment variable or better, use the full path when invoking `make`.   Another possibility is  the `make` is not using the desired shell when running.  This can be corrected by having the first statement in the makefile be:  `shell=shellpath/name`